# Avoid a character set in the meta tag but can't get it working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to get a good score for my WordPress site on different Page Speed sites. One of the problems I am facing is the following:

**Avoid a character set in the Meta tag**

I use IIS 7 and have control over it. So I went to the HTTP headers section an added:
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

After this change the website won't load anymore in IE, its starts downloading. So it seems that all of the content is seen as html and not CSS for example.

Anyone know how to fix this? I already tried to set the charset in the MIME types for HTML but this doesn't work either. Maybe cause it is PHP?

Comment: This sounds like you add that header to _every_ file delivered, not only for html files. Obviously that will cause problems for files like style sheets and the like. So the question is: _where_ (_when_) do you set that http header?

Comment: Is all your files encoded to utf-8? Just changing your header doesn't make your file utf-8 encoded. You are just say to the browser which char table to use.

Comment: I have set the header in IIS under http header, here I have added Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8